# pyuic5 backward compatibility

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyuic

Is there some sort of backward compatibility with the pyuic5 shell command?
I updated to pyQt5 a while ago, but I have a few projects running with pyQt4 on a separate python 3.4 environment. Unfortunately the pyuic4 shell command is now unavailable.
How can I convert .ui files to pyQt4 compatible code?

Comment: A solution (although you might have reasons for not wanting to do this) is to not convert the ui file to code, but load the ui files dynamically at run time through `PyQt4.uic.loadUi()`. That would require modifying the projects you have though, so perhaps not something you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your Python virtual environment, run

```
python -m PyQt4.uic.pyuic
```

followed by the standard options and arguments you would usually pass to pyuic4

Answer (score 0):

`PyQt5` is not compatibile with `PyQt4`, hence `pyuic5` is also not backward compatible. 
You can install `pyqt4-dev-tools` package on a debian based system which includes the `pyuic4` utility

Comment: I'm currently on windows 10. Is there no workaround, even if I have both pyQt versions installed on different environments?

Comment: @MisterTea I'm sorry I don't know any other alternative solution for Windows